# Problem in deploying Drupal 8 application

Tags: debugging, installation, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Drupal 8 application to another folder from development.
Using PGSQL as database server.
I have database named `xyz`.
I am copying that database to another one named `abc`.
The problem I am facing:
When I use old database `xyz` for new code base, it is running fine.
But, when I use `abc`, which is exact copy of `xyz`, it is showing error.
Following is the error I am facing:

```
Array
(
    [%type] => Recoverable fatal error
    [@message] => Drupal\Core\Render\Markup Object
        (
            [string:protected] => Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::__construct() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php on line 890 and defined
        )

    [%function] => Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->__construct()
    [%file] => /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php
    [%line] => 119
    [severity_level] => 3
    [@backtrace_string] => #0 /PROJECT-PATH/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(552): _drupal_error_handler_real(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/Applications/M...', 119, Array)
#1 /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(119): _drupal_error_handler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/Applications/M...', 119, Array)
#2 /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(890): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->__construct(false)
#3 /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(465): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
#4 /PROJECT-PATH/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(655): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()
#5 /PROJECT-PATH/index.php(23): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#6 {main}
)

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

Can somebody please help me solving this.

**EDIT:**

I have correctly changed `settings.php` file for new code base and also changed the correct database name.

Comment: If you are running Drupal on Linux could you check if the file has sufficient permissions (755).

Comment: Please post the snippet of your settings.php. (obfuscate ip  addresses.)